# Facing SSH connection issue during jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 servers on AWS EC2. I want to deploy our node JS application into both the instances. 
My below code is working fine if both the instances are available.

node (label: 'test') {

```
def sshConn = 'ssh -i /home/ec2-user/pem/ourpemfile.pem ec2-user@IP for server1' 
def sshConn1 = 'ssh -i /home/ec2-user/pem/ourpemfile.pem ec2-user@IP for server2'

stage('Checkout from Github')
{
    checkout([
         $class: 'GitSCM',
              *

              *        
            ]) 
}

stage('Build for Node1')
{
    echo "Starting to Build..."
    sh "$sshConn pm2 stop application || true"

}
stage('Deploy to Node1')
{
    echo "Starting Deployment..."
```

"
    }

```
 stage('Build for Node2')
{
    echo "Starting to Build..."
    sh "$sshConn1 pm2 stop application || true"

}
stage('Deploy to Node2')
{
    echo "Starting Deployment..."

}
```

}

But my use cases is .

if one of the server will stopped then build job must be successful and application should deploy on available instance.

Currently, I am facing timeout error if we stop server1 and run the jenkins job.

Comment: Use try-catch arround the commands

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your setup.

1) you can connect your nodes to jenkins as slaves vi ssh-slaves plugin. 
And then you can run on your servers via

```
node('node_label') {
  sh('any command here')
}
```

2) you can use ssh-agent plugin. You can put your private key into Jenkins credentials 
3) use retry

```
retry(3) {
// your code
}
```

Comment: I have created jenkins setup as below. I have installed jenkins on prod and 2 slave machine created one for test and other for dev.  By using prod jenkins url we are configuring our pipeline jobs. We defind label like test or dev in job. Every environment we have 2 servers. Where i want to deploy our application.  First we established  ssh connection in both server then we deploy our application. I am facing issue if I stoppped one server.

Answer (score 0):

You can check ec2 instances states via aws-cli commands, and depending on theirs states do or not you deployment :

If you want to give it a shot, you'll have to declare your AWS credentials in jenkins using 'CloudBees AWS Credentials' plugin.

and add to your pipeline something like that:

```
        withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
        accessKeyVariable: 'aV',
        secretKeyVariable: 'sV',
        credentialsId: 'id_of_your_credentials',]]) {
            sh '''
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${aV}\
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${sV}\
            AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1\
            aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[?Tags[?Key == 'Name' && contains(Value, 'server1')]].[Tags[3].Value,NetworkInterfaces[0].PrivateIpAddress,InstanceId,State.Name]" --output text
            '''
    }
```

Regardless to the AWS cli cmd :
I don't know how you manage your servers, I've assumed that you use a tag 'Name' to identify your servers.

Also, I think you should consider max suggestion and use ssh plugin for managing the configuration, credentials ...etc...

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be using ssh-agent. You have to store private keys in credentials plugin (also possible to configure AWS secrets for that)

and then in your pipeline

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/

```
node {
  sshagent (credentials: ['deploy-dev']) {
    sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l cloudbees 192.168.1.106 uname -a'
  }
}
```